# Java: How to not allow variable to go below 0

Tags: java, string, class, object, variables

I have a counter class I am testing. The counter increments up or down by 1. However, I do not want the number to go below zero, and I want to output an error message when the counter is set to a negative value. Below is the code for my counter class. Also, I am unsure how to have the boolean test display a string stating two instances of the counter are (or are not) equal. Thanks for your help.

```
public class Counter {

    private int counter;

    public Counter() {
        counter = 0;
    }

    //mutator adds 1 to counter
    public void plus1(){
        setCounter(getCounter() + 1);
    }

    //mutator subtracts 1 from counter
    public void minus1(){
        setCounter(getCounter() - 1);
    }

    //mutator
    public void setCounter(int newCounter){
        counter = newCounter;
    }

    //accessor
    public int getCounter(){
        return counter;
    }

    //polymorph
    public String toString(){
        return "The counter is currently at " + counter + ".";
    }

    public boolean equals(Counter a){
        return this.getCounter() == a.getCounter();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `minus1()` method, just check if the `counter` is already `0`; if it is, show your error and don't subtract again...

Comment: Your coding education and your question would both be improved by at least trying to implement this before coming here and then showing your attempt in your question. This in fact is required for homework questions on this site. Even if you have no clue as to a solution, an attempt, any attempt, will help sharpen your focus on the problem.

Comment: Note that your `equals` method doesn't correctly override `equals`: the parameter should be of `Object` type. And you should also override `hashCode` too.

Comment: @Zephyr that would be sufficient (nearly) if `setCounter` were private (or didn't exist). As it is, you need to check the value of `newCounter` there (too). (Nearly, because you need to check for overflow in the plus1 method too).

Comment: @Zephyr Thanks. Completely blanked on that. It worked well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for the information. I had completely blanked on how to do what I needed. Attempts will be shown in future posts.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. I'll dig into that some more.

Comment: @CitadelOne: good. Good luck

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OP wrote the whole class by himself, so an attempt was shown. And it wouldn't be a big deal to help him out with a single condition.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko but that condition is the entire crux of the OP's question.

Comment: @CitadelOne (1) setters are up to control the range of values allowed to be set in a private field. You should think of every possible `newCounter` that might come to `setCounter(int newCounter)` and write that logic there; what if `newCounter == 0`, what if `newCounter > 0`, what if `newCounter < 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer your questions one-by-one:

- not let counter set to -ve value using minus1(): for this you could add conditions like

```
if(counter == 0)
    throw new IllegalStateException("counter already 0"); // could be another exception type
```

- not let counter set to -ve value using setCounter(newCounter)

```
if(newCounter < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("counter cannot be negative"); // could be another exception type
```

- boolean test display a string whether counter is equal:

not sure if you are trying to override Object#equals method then your method signature is wrong and it could be

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Counter that = (Counter) o;
        return counter == that.counter;
    }
```

You could use some logger to print the String